# Percentage of total in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I know this is a ridiculously obvious question, but I'm not getting the way SQL queries need to be combines. I have a table named Customers and I need to calculate the percentage of total customers that have the value x as 99. There are only three columns in the table.

So far I've got `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM customer WHERE x=99` and `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM customer`, but I'm not sure how to divide one by the other in a single query. I have tried `SELECT (COUNT (*) FROM t_customer))/(Count (*) FROM t_customer WHERE customer_x=99))` but obviously I'm doing it very wrong! I'm using SQLite3. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred method is:

```
SELECT AVG(case when x = 99 then 1.0 else 0 end)
FROM customer;
```

I believe the following also works:

```
SELECT AVG(x = 99)
FROM customer ;
```

Comment: @DaveC: Taking the `AVG` of a Boolean (0=false, 1=true) expression gives you the proportion of its values that are true.